# Why MLR (monotone likelihood ratio) implies stochastic increasing?

Tags: probability, statistics

the following argument holds:
for $\theta_1<\theta_2$, $\dfrac{f(x\mid\theta_2)}{f(x\mid\theta_1)}$ is increasing in $x$. Then, $F(x\mid\theta_2)\leq F(x\mid\theta_1)$ for all $x$.

Intuitively, this seems to be natural but I could not find a way.
Would you let me know this or have some hints?

Comment: I feel doubtful on your statement. According to the definition of MLR, $\dfrac{f(x\mid\theta_2)}{f(x\mid\theta_1)}$ can be either nonincreasing or nondecreasing. It is not necessarily increasing in x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's suppose all is one-dimensional, and denote $g(x) = \dfrac{f(x\mid\theta_2)}{f(x\mid\theta_1)}$, then $g$ is increasing.

Define $t = \sup\{x: g(x) \leq 1\}$, then obviously for all $x \leq t$, $F(x\mid\theta_2)\leq F(x\mid\theta_1)$ since on $(-\infty,t)$ $f(x\mid\theta_2) \leq f(x\mid\theta_1)$ and $F(x\mid\theta_i) = \int_\infty^x f(y\mid\theta_i)dy, i = 1,2$

And for $x > t$, remark that $F(x\mid\theta_i) = 1 - \int^\infty_x f(y\mid\theta_i)dy, i = 1,2$ and on $(t, +\infty)$ we have $f(x\mid\theta_2) \geq f(x\mid\theta_1)$

Comment: Thank you so much. It helps me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

read this paper in page 5, solution of question 4 https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring07/sta215/hw/hw4_sol.pdf

Comment: I can't easily read your Answer, possibly a simple matter of formatting, although it seems pretty short.  Mathematical expressions can be posted using [MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score -3):

Sometimes it is good learning about doubts. This relation is well known from the beginning of mathematical statistics. In the classic book of Lehmann "Testing Statistical Hypothesis" you can find this implication and more.